# How to validate a select filed(drop down) with angular js. when click on a button

Tags: angularjs

How to validate a select filed(drop down) with angular js. when click on a button
validate for a empty value

button always need to be enabled.
if drop down have 'select value' as default option then prompt a error when button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

[Here (Plunker)](https://plnkr.co/edit/e9HgKtxPPCMyLMF15LzI?p=preview) is raw implementation of your functionality.

We basically have two parts:

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body ng-app="MyApp">
     <div ng-controller = "MyAppCtrl">
       <h1>Validating input</h1>

       <form ng-submit="submit(dropSelection)">
         <label for="search.mode">Select: </label>
         <select ng-model="dropSelection" ng-options="opt for opt in options"></select>
         <button type="submit">Validate</button>
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>

 </html>
```

**`app.js`**

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyAppCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.options = ["opt 1", "opt 2", "opt 2", "opt 3"];

  $scope.submit = function(selection){
    if(selection === undefined){
      alert('ERROR: Plese select option!');
    }else{
      alert("You've selected: " + selection );
    }

  };

 });
```